# Serializing Field Objects

Tags: java, serialization

I've written a generic database that indexes all the fields of an instance of a class that have a specific annotation. I need to be able to write an instance of this database to a file, but the [Field object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) doesn't implement serializable and is final.

Is there anyway around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get away with storing just the *names* of the fields (as strings, of course), since names must be unique within their declaring class. If you need to handle static members as well – and it's not clear that you do – store an additional `isStatic` boolean with each string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll give that a try - I don't need to handle static fields as I'm purely indexing an instance's unique fields.

Comment: So ... you're indexing the names of an objects instance fields ... but no data?

Comment: I'm also indexing the data, it's a simple implementation of an object DataBase with hashmaps.